# Turning off email notifications for individual group posts on Facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-groups, facebook-notifications

I am in a group and someone tagged me in a post and I got an email notification, this is fine and what I want.

However, what I *don't* want is email notifications every time someone else replies to this post, which I keep getting, I would *only*  want an email notification if they had directly replied to *me*.

Now I see you can turn off notifications to individual posts such as:

[image]

However I am unsure if this turns off email notifications *completely* and won't notify me now if someone tags me again or someones replies *directly* to me; I'm guessing it turns *all* notifications off.

Is there any way to do what I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unsubscribe directly from your email for which you don't want to be notify.

Suppose someone else replies to the post, you will get an email, unsubscribe that one.